# Create files from a list of text files

Tags: files, io-redirection, ls, input

I created a file using:

```
$ ls > ls.txt
```

Now I want to go to a different directory and use this file to create a bunch of empty files with the names from each line of `ls.txt`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I dont think anyone has mentioned this yet, but you shouldnt be parsing `ls`; use shell globs instead (or `find -print0` in conjunction with `xargs -0`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `xargs`. After changing to the new directory,

```
xargs -d '\n' touch -- < path/to/ls.txt
```

Note that if there were originally any directories in the `ls` output, these will be created as plain files in the new location.

Comment: COMPLETE. SORCERCY !!  
or maybe I need to learn this `xargs` command

Comment: Right now, it's magic.  Peruse the man page and it will simply be sufficiently advanced technology.

Comment: Note also that the newline character can (usually) appear in a valid filename, in which case `ls` will output it verbatim.  Then this command will create two files.

Comment: A shorter version with `cat` and IMHO more mnemonic: `cat list | xargs touch --`

Comment: @Hotschke if you omit the `-d '\n'` then it will fail if any of the names in the list contains whitespace

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks for pointing this out. Maybe the creator of the list of the filenames is aware of having whitespace and then needs `-d '\n'`. I agree this should be said in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Let me encourage you to take a step back.

It sounds like your actual problem is: “I have some files in my current directory, and I want to create empty files of the same names in a different directory.”

You supposed that a reasonable way to do this would be to start by saving the results of `ls` to a file. A reasonable assumption, but certainly not the only way to do it!

How about the following?

```
for filename in *; do
    touch -- "/path/to/somewhere/else/${filename}"
done
```

where `/path/to/somewhere/else/` is the directory in which you want to create the files.

This approach is simple and easy to read. Furthermore, it is completely robust to whitespace, newlines, and special characters in the filenames. It does not break if your profile has aliased `ls` to something like `ls --color`.

A disadvantage is that if you have really a lot of files, then this might be doing lots of extra work. But don’t worry about that until it actually becomes a problem.*

Another disadvantage is that if there are no files in your current directory, this will create a file literally called `*`. You can avoid this by writing `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop.

Note that (as with other solutions) if you have a directory `d` in your current directory, then a new empty file `d` will be created at the target. If you wish to avoid this, you could write:

```
for filename in *; do
    if [ -f "${filename}" ]; then
        touch -- "/path/to/somewhere/else/${filename}"
    fi
done
```

to only process normal files.

---

* If it is a problem: `printf '\0\n' * | (cd /path/to/somewhere/else; xargs -0 touch --)` will do the trick nicely.

Comment: Like that you told the advantages and disadvantages of your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
OFS=$IFS; 
IFS=$'\n';
cd to_new_location;
for file in `cat /path/to/ls.txt`; do
   touch $file;
done;
IFS=$OFS;
```

Comment: This will have problems if any of the original filenames contained whitespace: better to re-write as `while IFS= read -r file; do touch "$file"; done < path/to/ls.txt`

Comment: Not exactly sure why you would require a while, when we are talking about spaces.

Comment: Well before you recent edit, you didn't set IFS to newline so the result of `cat /path/to/ls` would have be subject to word splitting - I still think a `while` loop is a better idiom

Comment: I am guessing because it forces you to use the read command so it reduces the risk (word splitting) of having to know anything about your data?

Answer (score 0):

`sed "s/\(.*\)/touch '\1'/" < ls.txt | sh`

this turns the file into a shell script that creates the files with `touch`, and writes that script into a shell session. Run this command from the folder where you want the files. Replace `ls.txt` with its fully qualified name if it is in a different folder.